# Where to find elasticSearch index settings documentation?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using SpringData to connect to ElasticSearch.
When I create an index I can specify the settings using the `@Settings` annotation. [1]

This annotation accept a path to a json file, but I can't find any documentation about how this JSON file should be constructed and/or which option are available.

Anyone has some suggestions here?

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearc.misc.index.settings

Comment: just as an fyi it's Elasticsearch, not ElasticSearch :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-settings). The JSON for the `@Setting` annotation contains what is sent as the value of the `settings` property. Referring to the above linked dos, that would be:

```json
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,  
    "number_of_replicas": 2 
  }
}
```